# how to use type as key of another type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

As shown in the example below, I'm trying to make this behavior, as I want to pass the component name dynamically alongside its props

any suggestions?

as the current implementation is not working as expected

```js
type AllowedComponents = 'A' | 'B' | 'C'

type StepProps = {
  A: AProps,
  B: BProps,
  C: CProps
}

function someFn(componentName:AllowedComponents, props : stepProps[typeof componentName] ){
....
}
```

Comment: It looks like you want `someFn` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WvaKRm).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I can write up a full answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes, this is exactly what I need :)

thank you and waiting for the full answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `someFn()` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), as follows:

```
function someFn<K extends AllowedComponents>(componentName: K, props: StepProps[K]) { }
```

The generic type parameter `K` is constrained to the `AllowedComponents` type, so it can only be one of the allowed component names. And the `componentName` parameter is of type K. The `props` parameter is of the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `StepProps[K]`, so its type will be the props type for the given `componentName`.

In this way, the `someFn()` function can be used to pass a component name and its corresponding props to a function in a type-safe way. Here's an example of how you might use it:

```
declare const aProps: AProps;
declare const bProps: BProps;
someFn("A", aProps); // okay!
someFn("A", bProps); // error!
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIEEAKAnA9pAzrAvLA3rAIYBcsAjLAL5hRwBCK6WuBARqQExU0ywDCjTDnywAxqQDM3HnADKoaJEHN8wWAlJI0mADRrYdUg20Y96vqQEng1GQgA291AHdoAEz6oAtpFQA7aD9QFQBraHBUADNYeUVlAG4QSIBXP1FQAEt-WAxvaAAxPwAeAGlYaAAPBT83LHhHF3dPH39A4IA+AApRb18AoIA5Qi9oUhKdWEgTUlilEwBtEoBdAEpVGxA3aFF7QmQ4Hr8MUCJlTQTgLZ29g-9j2FYzgwvckcLOgCJ4D4nCZRX4rAAPRA2CoEKEcAAQmArwKfk+3wmjxMAOBoOgyDQyChQA)